# execute shell script code depends upon php return value

Tags: php, bash, shell

I haven't that  much of knowledge in PHP, and I need to run a script that depends upon the PHP return value.

### script

```
presentDir=`pwd`
success=$(php -f $presentDir/optimize.php $file)
echo echo "value:".$success
```

### PHP code

```
<?php
try{        
    //code  
} catch(Exception $e){
    return 1
}
return 0
```

When executing the above shell script, success is empty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PHP's `return` statement doesn't send any output to STDOUT, which is what you'd be catching with the `$()` construct. To see the exit value from a command you use [the `exit` statement](http://php.net/exit) in PHP and the [shell's `$?` variable](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html). Maybe this is what you're looking for?

```
<?php
try {
    //code
} catch(Exception $e){
    exit(1);
}
exit(0);
?>
```

Followed by:

```
#!/bin/sh
php -f optimize.php "$file"
printf "PHP script returned %d" $?

# or you could just use if:
if php -f optimize.php "$file"; then
    do_stuff
fi
```

There's no need to include the current working directory in a script call. (Further to that, you could make the script executable and call it directly!)

Comment: I had to add the brackets after exit statements, now it works fine. I edited the answer according to this fix.